# Pythonic way to return an array of the correct dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a function that returns a numpy array if one is given, or a multi-dimensional numpy array if that is given.  For example:

```
import numpy as np;
def running_average(data,windowSize):
    dShape = np.shape(data);
    if(len(dShape)==1):
        raOut = np.zeros(len(data));
        rSum = 0.0;
        for row,value in enumerate(data):
            if row<windowSize:
                rSum+=float(value);
            else:
                rSum=rSum-data[row-windowSize]+value;
            raOut[row]=rSum/windowSize;
    else:
        raOut = np.zeros(dShape);
        for col in xrange(dShape[1]):
            rSum=0.0;
            for row,value in enumerate(data[:,col]):
                if row<windowSize:
                    rSum+=float(value);
                else:
                    rSum=rSum-data[row-windowSize,col]+value;
                raOut[row,col]=rSum/windowSize;

    return raOut;
```

But there must be a good test to do so I don't have to essentially repeat myself in the if and the else statement.

I am newer to python, what is the prefferred method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
def running_avg(data, ws):
    tmp = np.cumsum(data, axis=-1, dtype='float')
    ra = (tmp[..., ws:] - tmp[..., :-ws]) / ws
    return ra
```

This will take the average on the last axis, if you wanted to get really clever you could have the function take an axis argument and take the average on an arbitrary axis.

UPDATE

I believe this version is consistent with your code above.

```
def running_avg(data, ws):
    ra = np.cumsum(data, axis=-1, dtype='float') / ws
    ra[..., ws:] = ra[..., ws:] - ra[..., :-ws]
    return ra
```

For your more general question, using numpys builtin functions, such as cumsum helps because they already do that, but if you do have to loop you can use A = np.zeros(A.shape) to get an array the same shape as the input and then use A[..., i] to always operate on the last dimension or A[..., i, :] to always operate on the second to last dimension and so on. Also sometimes people do data = np.roll(data, axis) to move axis to the beginning then you use A[i] to operative on the first dimension and move the axis back if you need to.

UPDATE 2:

I just remembered why the following is a very bad idea (at least in this case):

```
ra[..., ws:] -= ra[..., :-ws]
```

You should use this instead:

```
ra[..., ws:] = ra[..., ws:] - ra[..., :-ws]
```

Comment: Your clearly right that cumsum is the way to go to solve the running average problem.  However, I was more wondering how to solve the dimensional problem.  This would be solved in cumsum in this case...so I guess I could look and see how numpy did it.  Also, I don't think this works correctly for the ra[0:ws]

Comment: It looks like numpy uses the axis param, and if the input is multi-dimension and there is no axis param given they flatten the array and return cumsum on the whole thing.

Comment: It's pretty common in numpy, if no axis is given most functions that take an axis flatten the array. I believe that's different from matlab which always operates on the first or the last by default, I forget which.

Comment: ra = r_[tmp[...,:ws],(tmp[..., ws:] - tmp[..., :-ws])] / ws and I think it would work as expected

Comment: Yes, your updated code is the best.  And the paragraph below it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: sorry I forgot the `ra[..., ws:] -= ra[..., :-ws]` syntax doesn't behave as you (or at least I) might expect. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're overthinking the shape thing.  `np.zeros(dShape)` will do what you want whether `data` is a one-dimensional or a two-dimensional array.  (In the case of a one-dimensional array, `dShape` will be a one-element tuple, and `zeros` knows what to do with that.)

Second, stop putting semi-colons at the end of lines and parentheses in your if statements. This is Python, you don't need them.

As for repeating the code, I'd take everything in the `for row, value in ...` loop and abstract it into an iterator.

So:

```
import numpy as np

def average_iterator(data, windowSize):
  rSum = 0.0
  for row, value in enumerate(data):
    if row < windowSize:
      rSum += float(value)
    else:
      rSum = rSum - data[row-windowSize] + value
    yield row, rSum / windowSize

def running_average(data, windowSize):
  dShape = np.shape(data)
  raOut = np.zeros(dShape)
  if len(dShape) == 1:
    for row, avg in average_iterator(data, windowSize):
      raOut[row] = avg
  else:
    for col in xrange(dShape[1]):
      for row, avg in average_iterator(data[:,col], windowSize):
        raOut[row, col] = avg
  return raOut
```

You could also make `average_iterator` a local definition inside `running_average`, in which case you wouldn't have to pass in `windowSize`.

Comment: Yeah, it's like I have a really bad Matlab accent when I speak python.  I am working on it(not enough obviously), thanks for reminding me.  Anyway, I like your iterator idea but combined with aganders3's try/except method.  Thanks for your answer cause it really did help me, but I think I have to give it to him because the repetition is still there in yours, just behind another function

Answer (score 1):

I like Peter's answer, but here is an alternative with fewer changes to your code. Just test for the number of columns - consider it 'one' if you don't have any.

```
import numpy as np
def running_average(data,windowSize):
    dShape = np.shape(data)

    try:
        dShape[1]
    except:
        data = [data]
        dShape = np.shape(data)

    raOut = np.zeros(dShape)
    for col in dShape[1]:
        rSum=0.0
        for row,value in enumerate(data[:][col]):
            if row<windowSize:
                rSum+=float(value)
            else:
                rSum=rSum-data[row-windowSize][col]+value
            raOut[row][col]=rSum/windowSize

    return np.squeeze(raOut)
```

Comment: Although, possibly it is not that easy.  When you do data=[data] on something (15L,) you get something with shape (1L,15L).  So it kind of transposes it for you.  So you then have to flip the dimensions in your code I think.

Comment: Hmmm...serves me right for not testing my code. Does it work if you just add in `data = np.transpose(data)` just after that line? Though I think we're starting to stray from pythonic territory...

Comment: True, not the point of the question...and yes, that would work also